# How can I get tapped location in flutter_map?

Tags: flutter, dart, fluttermap

I'm implementing a map in my code. So far this is what I have:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map_tappable_polyline/flutter_map_tappable_polyline.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class MapPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  MapPicker({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MapPicker createState() {
    return _MapPicker();
  }
}

class _MapPicker extends State<MapPicker> {
  Position _position;

  void getLocation() async {
    var position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    print(position);
    setState(() {
      _position = position;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(_position == null)
      getLocation();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text('Escoger Localización'),
      ),
      body: _position != null ? FlutterMap(
        options: MapOptions(
          center: LatLng(18.0119098, -66.6159138), //Change to _position
          zoom: 15.0
        ),
        layers: [
          TileLayerOptions(
              urlTemplate:
              "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
              subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
          MarkerLayerOptions(
            markers: [],
          ),
          TappablePolylineLayerOptions(
            onTap: (TaggedPolyline polyline) => print(polyline.tag)
          )
        ],
      )
          :
      CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using a set LatLon for now for test purposes but the idea is using `_position` to use the current position when opening the map. But, my problem is the following: I want to be able to tap any place in the map and get the coordinates for the place I tapped. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

```
options: new MapOptions(
            onTap: (tapPosition, point) => {
              print(point.toString()),
            },
            center: LatLng(0, 0),
            zoom: 1,
            maxZoom: 19,
          ),
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible through the `onTap()` callback I think available in `MapOptions()`. It returns the position tapped.